# how to remove parenthesis from list of MySQL select in python for compare list data via variable value

Tags: python, mysql, select, time

I want select some rows and save in a list from MySQL database and compare with variable value but the result is empty

this is my code:

```
mycursor = lucas_db.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT Release_Name FROM Lucas_Table WHERE Published_Time > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIME, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)

last=input('give me:')

me = difflib.get_close_matches(last, myresult)
print(me)
```

and the result is :

```
[('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time WEBRip x264-CAFFEiNE',), ('A Million Little Things S01E17 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('The Pioneer Woman S21E09 16-Minute Chicken 480p x264-mSD',), ('The Pioneer Woman S21E09 16-Minute Chicken AAC MP4-Mobile',), ('Northern Rescue S01E09 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time XviD-AFG',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time 480p x264-mSD',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time AAC MP4-Mobile',), ('How to Get Away with Murder S05E15 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('The Titan Games S01E09 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',)]
give me:The Pioneer Woman S21E09 16-Minute Chicken 480p x264-mSD

[]

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Rows are typically returned as immutable tuples; your best bet is probably to create a list of strings from the list of tuples returned by `fetchall()`, then use `get_close_matches()` with that

Comment: @DavidFaber 'my_list = myresult' like this???

Comment: No, something like this: `my_list = [res[0] for res in myresult]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myresult will be a list of tuples, with one element, the single select column from the database.

The following illustrates what is going on with difflib.

```
a = [('foo',),('bar',)]
difflib.get_close_matches('foo', a)
[]
a = [a[0] for a in a]
difflib.get_close_matches('foo', a)
['foo']
```

Comment: i think i didn't get your mean but i write like this but give an error

   my_list = [myresult]

 a = [my_list[0] for a in a]

 last=input('give me:')

 me = difflib.get_close_matches(last, a)
 print(me)

the error is:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "DB.py", line 45, in <module>
    >a = [my_list[0] for a in a]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

 ***Repl Closed***

Comment: You need to understand how to work with list comprehensions to adapt the above to your code.  Try myresult = [a[0] for a in myresult] where myresult is being enumerated tuple-wise and the first tuple element is inserted into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chain.from_iterable()` to chain all strings in `myresult`. You can also try to change the `cutoff` argument in `difflib.get_close_matches()`:

```
from itertools import chain
import difflib

myresult = [('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time WEBRip x264-CAFFEiNE',), ('A Million Little Things S01E17 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('The Pioneer Woman S21E09 16-Minute Chicken 480p x264-mSD',), ('The Pioneer Woman S21E09 16-Minute Chicken AAC MP4-Mobile',), ('Northern Rescue S01E09 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time XviD-AFG',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time 480p x264-mSD',), ('Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time AAC MP4-Mobile',), ('How to Get Away with Murder S05E15 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',), ('The Titan Games S01E09 720p HEVC x265-MeGusta',)]

c = chain.from_iterable(myresult)

print(difflib.get_close_matches('Food', c, cutoff=0.1))
```

Output:

```
['Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time XviD-AFG', 'Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time 480p x264-mSD', 'Food-Fact or Fiction S04E16 Tea Time AAC MP4-Mobile']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rich Andrews its worked:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT Release_Name FROM Lucas_Table WHERE Published_Time > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIME, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

myresult = [a[0] for a in myresult]

last=input('give me:')

me = difflib.get_close_matches(last, myresult)
print(me)
```

the result for "James Martins Great British Adventure S01E03 WEB x264-LiGATE" is :

```
give me:James Martins Great British Adventure S01E03 WEB x264-LiGATE
['James Martins Great British Adventure S01E09 WEB x264-LiGATE', 'James Martins Great British Adventure S01E11 WEB x264-LiGATE']

***Repl Closed***
```